# On iOS, how did Twitter make the profile banner animation when scrolling through?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation

I'm talking about the animation on user profiles. If you open someone's profile and swipe up to scroll down, the user's banner will blur into the navigation bar. If you swipe down to scroll up, the banner will get bigger and zoom in.

Here's some screenshots demonstrating the feature: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHLoE.png

Does anyone know how this is done? Is it something built-into iOS, or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: This is done by using a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and changing the layout of the screen based on scroll position.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `UIBlurEffectStyle`. Apple docs here (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBlurEffectStyle)

Comment: Looks like you want to read [this think & build article](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/implementing-the-twitter-ios-app-ui/), which pretty much shows how to do it using swift (and a pinch of objective-C)

Comment: How can i do touchable the header image?. Somebody knows?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that's similar to the twitter. I would suggest you check this

https://github.com/starchand/MBTwitterScroll